# Want to set different parameters per ListView item in Android

Tags: android, listview, iterator, margins

I am trying to set parameters (margins in this case) per item in listview.
But when i do, it just sets the margin of last iteration.

How can i set properties per item (row) in the listview?

Ultimately i want to set diffrent "gaps" beween the items (so i can use it for my custom calendarview)

Eventually setDividerHeight() per item is good too, but i have the same problem on that function; namely one value for height and not a variabhle that can be changed per row.

```
//for loop
for (int i = 0; i < planning.size(); i++) 
{
planning = getPlanning(medewerkerId, beginDate, eindDate);
int space = i * 15;


final ListView lijstje = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sundayList);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)       lijstje.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(0,space,0,0); // this wont work, and sets the height only on last iteration
lijstje.setAdapter(new PlanbordAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.planning_item, planning));


lijstje.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
 {
//onclick stuff here           
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to awnser my own question: Turns out i needed to use ".invalidate()" on the view in which i projected the list on, in order to redraw the items with correct margings set. hope this helps someone in the future with the same problem.